# SVG pattern with a path doesn't show up

Tags: html, svg

Why doesn't the path show up as pattern for the rect?

```
<svg>
    <defs>
        <pattern id="secondPattern" x="2" y="2" 
                 width="20" height="20" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">

            <path x="5" y="5" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="black"
                  d="M351.869,326.667c0,0-13.381-53.913,24.107-104.465 c-7.809,24.381-23.059,38.464-21.428,104.465"/>
        </pattern>
    </defs>

    <rect x="2" y="2" width="200" height="200" 
          stroke="#333333" stroke-width="2" fill="url(#secondPattern)" />

    <!--the same path here works: -->
    <path x="5" y="5" fill="red" stroke="black"
          d="M351.869,326.667c0,0-13.381-53.913,24.107-104.465 c-7.809,24.381-23.059,38.464-21.428,104.465"/>
</svg>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t5k5ppgb/

Comment: because the path is outside the bounds of the pattern.

Comment: @RobertLongson is right https://jsfiddle.net/t5k5ppgb/2/

Comment: @ZachSaucier What did you change? I don't see any changes - lost my glasses.

Comment: The width and the height of the pattern has to fit the path. since some of the points are in the 300s, you can change them to 400 and it works...

Answer (score 2):

This is what your pattern looks like:

[image]

The path is drawn somewhere around coordinate [350,250] (red rectangle), but because you set the pattern's `width` and `height` to 20, you say that only the top left 20x20 square should be used (green square). So, the pattern *is* used on the rect, but only an area that is empty.

If you want to keep the pattern size at 20x20 pixels, you need to tell the pattern to move and resize the interesting part into view. This can be done with the `viewBox` setting:

```
<pattern id="secondPattern" ... viewBox="300 200 130 140">
```

This says that what we want to display starts at coordinate [300,200], and starting at that coordinate, we want to show an area of 130x140px. Now, you can set the pattern's `width` and `height` to whatever you like, and the "toothpick" will always remain in view.

https://jsfiddle.net/t5k5ppgb/3/

*By the way, setting `x` and `y` on a `path` doesn't do anything.*